# foreach read multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

When I run I only get the contents of the `Month.txt` file, I understand this is only because I have set this as the string in the `foreach`, however I cannot work out how I also go about adding the other files to this as well do I get the contents of all the files and not just the Month?

```
string[] month = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
            (@"E:\project1\input\Month.txt");

            string[] 1_AF = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
            (@"E:\project1\input\1_AF.txt");

            string[] 1_Rain = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
            (@"E:\project1\input\1_Rain.txt");

            string[] 1_Sun = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
            (@"E:\project1\input\1_Sun.txt");

            string[] 1_TBig = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
            (@"E:\project1\input\1_TBig.txt");

            string[] 1_TSmall = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
            (@"E:\project1\input\1_TSmall.txt");

            System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of all files =:");
            foreach (string months in month)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(months + "\t" + 1_AF + "\t" + 1_Rain + "\t" + 1_Sun + "\t" + 1_TBig + "\t" + 1_TSmall);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You have to create list of array and add the individual file content into that List,  then you can apply foreach for array

Comment: Have you considered using `List`, `Dictionary`, or `Tuple`? They are very useful for case like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` loop provides an iterator over the given collection. If you need data for multiple collections, then, you would need multiple iterators.

If all the arrays are of the same size, you can always use a *traditional* `for` loop and use the numerical index to access the array locations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(month[i]+ "\t" + 1_AF[i] + "\t" + 1_Rain[i] + "\t" + 1_Sun[i] + "\t" + 1_TBig[i] + "\t" + 1_TSmall[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace SOFAcrobatics
{
    public static class Launcher
    {
        public static void Main (String [] paths)
        {
            List<String> pool = new List<String>();
            foreach (String path in paths)
            {
                pool.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(path));
            }
            // pool is now populated with all the lines of the files given from paths
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will work even if you have arrays of different sizes. You can always use a single iterator if all arrays are of same size.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] a = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
        (@"E:\test\a.txt");

        string[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
        (@"E:\test\b.txt");

        string[] c= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
        (@"E:\test\c.txt");

        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of all files =:");
        for (int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0; x < a.Length || y < b.Length || z < c.Length; x++,y++,z++)
        {
            string first = string.Empty, second = string.Empty, third = string.Empty;

            if (x < a.Length)
                first = a[x];
            if (y < b.Length)
                second = b[y];
            if (z < c.Length)
                third = c[z];

            Console.WriteLine("\t" + first + "\t" + second + "\t" + third);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```